# Vlookup Function will not find correct values

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a simple index file which will cycle through 500+ files and will retrieve relevant information.  One of the index fields is a `VLookUp`, which references another sheet in the active index Workbook.  While testing the script, the `VLookUp` function cannot find the appropriate value, even though it will when I manually enter the same formula into a cell.  Any ideas why this might be happening (it returns "N/A" every time, as indicated by the ErrorHandling):

```
Public Sub UpdateIndex()

Dim RowNumber As Integer, LookUpLast As Integer
Dim Control As String, PartNumber As String, PartDescription As String, Rev As String
Dim LookUp As Range, IndexLookup As Variant

Control = "Arbitrary"
RowNumber = 2
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet2)
LookUpLast = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set LookUp = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LookUpLast, 2)) 'Had previously tried Range("A2", "B" & LookUpLast)
End With

    IndexLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookUp(Control, LookUp, 2, False)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1)
        .Range("D" & RowNumber) = IndexLookup
    End With

    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1

Next File

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    IndexLookup = "N/A"
    Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You made some modification to `LookUp`, can you verify that the range is set correctly?

Comment: @Bmo I tried to add `LookUp` to the Watch and I then proceeded to step into my code, but I couldn't find any verification that the range was correct.  The `LookUpLast` variable is correct, so I can't figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: @pnuts, I'm not sure how I can provide a more insightful example.  I try to run the script and receive an error on the `VLookUp` line.  I tried changing the variable name and re-dimensioned it (in case the variable `VLookUp` was causing conflict), but still no luck.  Is there a way to verify the range that is set by LookUp?

Comment: @pnuts, thank you for the input.  I was debating whether or not I should include the entire script, but I figured I might have called a variable incorrectly or done something wrong in a line other than the one which is drawing the error.  I can try to edit the script to a more manageable size!

Comment: @pnuts, thank you!  As you can tell, I am new to SO and still learning my way around.  I tried Option Explicit, but still no luck.  I might try making the cell Formula a `VLOOKUP`, but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

Comment: Can you add this line after your `Set LookUp` line: `Debug.Print LookUp.Address`. This should help you see if the range is what you are expecting.

Comment: @guitarthrower I added `Msgbox LookUp.Address` and it produced "$A$2:$B$561", which is the correct range.  I'm wondering if maybe I need to associate a worksheet with it.  I tried `Worksheets(Sheet2).LookUp.Address`, but still no success.

Comment: @CJK Looking closer it looks like you aren't giving `Control` a value. The vlookup is looking for a null value, which may be why this isn't working. Also, I would change your return variable to `MyVlookup` to avoid any confusion with the built-in formula. It may not have any impact, but it's a good idea to reuse built-in names.

Comment: @guitarthrower I apologize, I stripped my code to make it less customized and accidentally removed the value for `Control` (which is an arbitrary string depending on the file being opened).  I did change `VLookUp` to `IndexLookUp` previously, but still no luck.

Comment: It's `not` a good idea to reuse built-in names ;)

Comment: @guitarthrower Ah, are you referencing `Control`?  I guess I managed to use two built-in names... Whoops!  I will change both `Control` and `VLookUp`!

Comment: One more thing to try, is to `debug.print Control` in the immediate window, and try and do a Vlookup formula in the worksheet with the text it returns to see if that throws an error in the Excel formula. If so, then you have a problem with your `Control` variable. Otherwise, it sounds like the formula works while in the spreadsheet, but VBA isn't working, for some reason that may be difficult to figure out here. (I've been there before too, fun times!) What about a different approach? add the formula using the `Range.Formula` field and fill down, then replace with just the values and move on.

Comment: @guitarthrower When I step into the script, `Control` is the correct value, and from the previous `Msgbox`, so is `LookUp`.  I genuinely cannot figure out why it won't function properly (I believe I keep receiving a 1004 error).  I will continue working on it tonight, and maybe I'll reach a solution!

Comment: the reason i suggest a copy paste, is that sometimes there can be leading/trailing spaces, and it may not be what it seems. Hence putting the text it is returning into the formula on a spreadsheet.

Comment: @guitarthrower, I might have to.  If I manually type this formula into a cell `=VLOOKUP("2366",VLOOKUP!$A$2:$B$561, 2, FALSE)`, it works fine.  The "2366" is an arbitrary number, and the range in `VLOOKUP!` is exactly the same as `LookUp.Address`.  I am just baffled as to why this is not working.

Comment: I think the problem you may be having is a difference in type between the spreadsheet and the code. I.e. vba storing as text and spreadsheet as number or vice versa.

Comment: @guitarthrower I agree, I think the function is working but the lookup value is not registering. This would also make sense as I am receiving a "Number stored as text" error for some of the lookup values.  Do you have any suggestions for ensuring that the function is reading the table properly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51463/discussion-between-cjk-and-guitarthrower)

Comment: You could try and change the variable `Control` type from `String` to `Variant`. Most likely the reason for the error is type mismatch, that will generate an error in VLookup function. If you place number 4 in to a string it will be converted automatically to a string. The result is the same as in code the line written as `"4"` is not same as `4`.